# Import Excel with different columns in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2005

i want to import excel with variable no. of columns into dynamic table in MS SQL Server 2005.
problem : since column are not fixed table structure is also not fixed so how to proceed.

Comment: Could you at least show us how your MS Excel file looks like (i.e. format) and probably make it to an image file and then show here.

Comment: will provide shortly..

Comment: how to upload image file edper

Comment: put it on tinypic.com then provide the link and we will be the one post it here after.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution to your question, but this might help you.

- Create a Table in Database with Enough number of columns (for example 50
  or 100 columns with a name Temporary)
- Whenever an Excel file comes for Importing data import the data in
  this Temporary table
- Then Show the imported data to the user for Validation and Mapping with the table where record must go
- Ask user in which table he wants to put the data from Temporary
  table, which Fields of Temporary table are mapped to fields of the
  desired Table and then Insert data into that table

This will be helpful only if you want to import data like customers. But if you want to import data like daily transactions which can be voluminous, then showing imported data to user and then asking him for mapping can be non user friendly option.